# Hibernate HQL with a Join Table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

This query, which used to work, no longer does.  (I'm switching to annotations, and this is one of two broken tests remaining.)

I've got three tables:

```
+---------------+
| Competition   | 
+---------------+
| competitionId | 
| . . .         | 
+---------------+

+---------------+
| Competitor    | 
+---------------+
| competitorId  | 
| . . .         | 
+---------------+

+------------------------+
| CompetitionCompetitors | 
+------------------------+
| competitionId          | 
| competitorId           | 
+------------------------+
```

And the code/query that used to work is

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "select c.id from Competition c join c.competitors co where co.id = :competitorId" );
query.setParameter( "competitorId", competitor.getCompetitorId() );
List list = query.list();
```

Here's some of the preceding SQL logging coming from Hibernate, plus the error message:

```
Hibernate: update db.competition set competitorId=? where competitionId=?
Hibernate: update db.competition set competitorId=? where competitionId=?
Hibernate: update db.competition set competitorId=? where competitionId=?
17:12:49,232  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:233 - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
17:12:49,240 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:234 - Unknown column 'competitorId' in 'field list'
```

(Gotta admit, I was surprised to see updates occurring on a query.)

Here's the annotations in Competition:

```
@OneToMany( targetEntity = Competition.class )
@JoinColumn( name = "competitorId" )
private Set< Competitor > competitors = new TreeSet< Competitor >();
```

What did I flub up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is a minor copy-paste error - the query you construct is 'query' but the one you execute is 'otherQuery'?

However, the problem I believe, is in the targetEntity value. From the spec:

> The entity class that is the target of the association. Optional only if the collection-valued relationship property is defined using Java generics. Must be specified otherwise.

In your case you either have to specify `Competitor.class` or leave it out. You would have to specify the `JoinTable` annotation along with the `joinColumn` and `inverseJoinColumn` values as the default `JoinTable` that is going to be searched for is `Competitor_Competition`.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "CompetitionCompetitors", inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="competitorId")}, joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="competitionid")}
private Set< Competitor > competitors = new TreeSet< Competitor >();
```

I am not sure why those update statements are being executed if all you are doing is looking those values up.

Comment: So much to learn about mapping and JPA.  Thanks!  That got the query working.